# Возникает ошибка в PhpMyAdmin на OpenServer. Переношу работающий сайт с веб сервера на локальный, и такое ...?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, openserver

Возникает ошибка в PhpMyAdmin на OpenServer. Переношу работающий сайт с веб сервере на локальный, и загрузил файлы и базу данных. Зашел в базу данных в папку wp_options, нажимаю карандашил для редактирования siteurl и пишет такую ошибку. Скрины загрузил. Подскажите как исправить и в чем проблема . URL будет отличаться на локальном сервере, чем тот, который на веб сервере. Подскажите в чем проблема ошибки и как это исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первое сообщение с ошибкой вроде как неплохо говорит что не так.

Comment: А в последнем скриншоте (наверху) даже по русски написано в чем проблема

Comment: это все весело что Вам все видно. Я учусь, и хотелось бы знать , как это исправить

Comment: Ну вам же в скрине 2 написали, что нужно увеличить значения такой-то переменной в php.ini. Вы это сделали?